# RPI not connecting the wifi

Tags: pi-4, boot, wpa-supplicant

As written I am unable to connect my RPI to the internet.
What happened is I took the RPI from the office (where it was working) and took it home (to a new wifi).
To save myself the headache, before I left the office I ssh'ed into the rpi and edited the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file. Once I got home I was unable to ssh and ping. This is what I have done to remedy the situation.
To attempt connection, I have:

1. taken out the SD card and connected it to my computer, and edited the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file. The contents are:

```
crt_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
ssid="xxxxxxx"
scan_ssid=1
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
psk="xxxxxxx"
}
```

Let the host name of this RPI be: `pi`.
I have tried to ping, i.e. `ping pi.local` which returns `ping: cannot resolve pi.local: Unknown host`.

Another way I have tried to get the IP address of the rpi is to do:
`sudo nmap -sn 192.168.86.0/25`
This command also does not list the rpi as a connected device.
What have I done wrong?

Another thing I have tried is to connect the rpi to a monitor to use the GUI.
Yes, I have edited the `config.txt` file and uncommented `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` and `hdmi_drive=2`
A problem with this method is that the monitor goes blank once the boot is mounted.

Any ideas on what I can do?
I would prefer to not have to flash a new image..

Is this helps, I see that I have an `issue.txt` file which contains:

```
Raspberry Pi reference 2022-09-22
Generated using pi-gen, https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, stage2
```

Should I edit the `cmdline.txt` file?

Comment: Remove `scan_ssid=1` and `key_mgmt=WPA-PSK` they are optional parms and WiFi won't work if they're wrong.

Comment: What Pi? What OS? How did you edit wpa_suppliccant? What does ip a and ip l show?

Answer (score 0):

The 1st line should be
`ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev`

The permissions MUST be `-rw------- 1 root root`

NOTE You can have multiple `network` sections for home & work (I have 9)
See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: Hey @Milliways, thank you for the response! I will try your suggested solution out in a few hours. However, I am unsure what you mean by: "The permissions MUST be `-rw------- 1 root root`"
What do you mean by that - can you please expand?

Comment: @NicholasFrańczak I asked for clarification in a Comment which you have not supplied. It is difficult to see how you modified the file if you don't  understand Linux permissions.